# Render multiple fusioncharts plots on the same chart using two or more data sources

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, fusioncharts

After banging my head against the wall all day i'm hoping to try and seek some help.

I am trying to use fusioncharts to render multiple timeseries plots on the same chart.

**Example**: [https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiontime/examples/plotting-multiple-series-on-time-axis](https://www.fusioncharts.com/fusiontime/examples/plotting-multiple-series-on-time-axis?framework=javascript)

The problem I face is the example code uses a data source that provides the required data for both plots in a single array, However, my requirements are to seek the data from two different endpoints (Example Below).

**/api/price**

```
[{"date":"1-Jul-21","price":10.04},{"date":"2-Jul-21","price":9.50},{"date":"3-Jul-21","price":18.25}]
```

**/api/stats**

```
[{"date":"1-Jul-21","stats":195},{"date":"2-Jul-21","stats":2046},{"date":"3-Jul-21","stats":1021}]
```

**Schema:**

```
[{"name":"date","type":"date","format":"%d-%b-%y"},{"name":"price","type":"number"},{"name":"stats","type":"number"}]
```

***Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.***

PS:  Fusioncharts use **createDataTable** which expects two arguments, a data object and the scheme object.  My initial thought was something like this createDataTable(data1, data2, schema) but it appears that is not possible and I somehow need a workaround or to ensure the data passed to **createDataTable** is handled before **createDataTable** is called..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createDataTable method takes two parameters one is the data & the other is a schema, since you want to display multiple series for the same date, assuming your data is coming from two API end points you can merge this two objects into a single data array, for example based on your above-shared data it will be as below

```
let schema = [{"name":"date","type":"date","format":"%d-%b-%y"},{"name":"price","type":"number"},{"name":"stats","type":"number"}]

let data = [["1-Jul-21",10.04, 195]]
```

Where 1-Ju-21 denotes date, 10.04 is the price value & 195 is stats value

Here is a similar demo : https://jsfiddle.net/px6fbj3L/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, could you please provide an example within your post for the best practice on merging the arrays for the key "date"? Both endpoints return the same dates. The api returns approx 1,000 - 2,000 rows for each endpoint so i guess i would need to loop over the arrays.

Comment: @Jrad51 Please use array filter map like methods : https://javascript.info/array-methods